# Styling only parent list

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-lists

I have the following ordered list:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <span>Title</span>

        <ol>
            <li>Info</li>
            <li>Info</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

With CSS I need to apply styling to only the parent `li`, so only the `1. Title` and not the child `ol`. How do I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
body > ol > li {
    /* Styling here */
}
```

and

```
body > ol > li > span {
    /* Styling here */
}
```

But neither gives the desired effect.

```css
body > ol > li {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/* Additional styling */
ol { counter-reset: item; }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <span>Title</span>
      <ol>
        <li>Info</li>
        <li>Info</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mhajeLf/1/)

Comment: maybe just giving a class to the list element e.g `parent` class and then style that class?

Comment: Your second option work in your jsfiddle also.

Comment: Its just effect to your parent <li> only.

Comment: If you need I will update your jsfiddle?

Comment: Check https://jsfiddle.net/6mhajeLf/2/

Comment: @ketan The problem is that the `1.` needs to be styled too

Comment: `body > ol > li:before { color: #FFF; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this CSS to your code:

```
span + ol {
  font-weight: initial;
  font-size: initial;
}
```

```css
body > ol > li {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}

span + ol {
  font-weight: initial;
  font-size: initial;
}

/* Additional styling */
ol { counter-reset: item; }
li { display: block }
li:before { content: counters(item, ".") ". "; counter-increment: item }
```

```html
<body>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <span>Title</span>
      <ol>
        <li>Info</li>
        <li>Info</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pw9kfa6z/)

Comment: children inherit font-weight and font-size properties from their parent. That's why you need this solution proposed by Blaze Sahlzen.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the only solution would be to reset the styling manually on the child `ol` like this:

```
ol ol {
  /* Reset styling */
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mhajeLf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve, you need to declare

```
body > ol > li:first-child { color: #FFF; }
body > ol > li:first-child > ol { color:#000; }
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/6mhajeLf/4/

Answer (score 0):

Even though Blaze Sahlzen has the best answer, here's **another possible solution**:

https://jsfiddle.net/6mhajeLf/6/

Done by adding a class to the items that don't need to be bold and using `!important`. A little bit dirty, but it works.

```
.not-bold {
  font-weight:300 !important;
}
```